# Invalid CFStringRef from ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook, cfstring

I'm getting telephone numbers from the address book. I'm doing it this way:

```
ABMultiValueRef arrTelefonos = ABRecordCopyValue(contacto,kABPersonPhoneProperty);
for(int i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(arrTelefonos);i++) {
   CFStringRef labelTelefono = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(arrTelefonos,i);
   CFStringRef numeroTelefono = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(arrTelefonos,i);
   CFStringRef labelTelefonoLoc = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(labelTelefono);
   /* Do some stuff */
}
```

Everything is Ok except in one case: If there is a contact with a phone labeled with special characters (in my case the label is: "Teléfono" with an "é" I'm getting an "invalid CFStringRef" when doing

```
CFStringRef labelTelefono = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(arrTelefonos,i);
```

Is there a problem due to CFStringRef doesn't allow special characters? If that's the problem, anyone know a solution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: A `CFStringRef` can definitely contain special characters.  What exactly tells you that the string is invalid; what do you do with the string?

Comment: Debbuging the application I saw the value "0x000000 Invalid CFStringRef" in the "labelTelefono" var. I remember that this contact was imported from another devise so it's probably that the label where "corrupted" due to rewritting the label now the application works but, the CFStringRef generated is "Tel.fono". Is it possible to get this character correctly?
(thank you for answering so quickly)

Comment: I think that mistery is solved:
1.- As I've said before, it's probable that the label of this contact were "corrupted" because rewriting it with the same character, it works fine
2.- The second mistery (I saw the label as "Tel.fono") was because I was seeing it into the debug console and it's not "friendly" with special characters
Thank you for our interest (your answer made me investigate more and it takes me to the solution :) )

Comment: Ah, OK.  The encoding is a property of the string itself; whoever creates the string has to choose an encoding that is sufficient for the characters (e.g. some encodings don't define accented letters).  Ideally Apple uses something pretty wide-open like UTF-8 but perhaps in this case they do not.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray *phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        ABMultiValueRef multiPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones);i++) {

            CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, i);
            NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *) phoneNumberRef;
            [phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];

            //NSLog(@"All numbers %@", phoneNumbers);

        }
```

Comment: he wantes the label and also he has the issue that for some reason the encoding of a string wasn't ok for him -- this seems 'related' but no answer (he solved it as can be read in the comments)